# Cannot finish implementing IDeskBand2 interface

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, com

I am trying to implement a DeskBand in the Taskbar for my app and I have checked the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646472.aspx) but it's very sparse. It does not explain how implement the IDeskBand2 interface.

I've found very little information online about this and the stuff I have found does not work. I found what looked to be a promising piece of code on CodeProject to be no more than a fountain of compiletime errors, until today, when I stumbled upon [this](http://www.windows-tech.info/13/3a5b1ddc39c490ac.php) website.

So far, what I've got is this:

```
class COMInterop
{
    [ComImport]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    [Guid("79D16DE4-ABEE-4021-8D9D-9169B261D657")]

    public interface IDeskBand2
    {
        void GetWindow(out System.IntPtr phwnd);
        void ContextSensitiveHelp([In] bool fEnterMode);
        void ShowDW([In] bool fShow);
        void CloseDW([In] UInt32 dwReserved);
        void ResizeBorderDW(IntPtr prcBorder, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] Object punkToolbarSite, bool fReserved);

        void GetBandInfo(UInt32 dwBandID, UInt32 dwViewMode, ref DESKBANDINFO pdbi);
        bool CanRenderComposited();
        bool GetCompositionState();
        void SetCompositionState(bool fCompositionEnabled);
    }
}
```

which is inside a Class file called `COMInterop.cs`.

The problem I have now is on line 24. It says `The type or namespace 'DESKBANDINFO` could not be found. (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do I implement this - and do you have any **good** documentation for a DeskBand (see pic below) for Windows 7+?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this [P/Invoke info](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/DESKBANDINFO.html) can help you?

Comment: Thanks @pasty, but now it says DBIM could not be found. I'm trying to search online to see why.

Comment: You could search the P/Invoke site for the structures you need ...

Comment: Don't write deskbands in .NET. Deskbands run inside the Explorer.exe process, and therefore shouldn't be written in .NET for all the same reasons [shell extensions shouldn't be written in .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/22/10396079.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DESKBAND` info is a struct documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773255.aspx). You can find a C# translation on [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/DESKBANDINFO.html).

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public POINT(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

    public POINT(System.Drawing.Point pt) : this(pt.X, pt.Y) { }

    public static implicit operator System.Drawing.Point(POINT p)
    {
        return new System.Drawing.Point(p.X, p.Y);
    }

    public static implicit operator POINT(System.Drawing.Point p)
    {
        return new POINT(p.X, p.Y);
    }
}

[StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
struct DESKBANDINFO {
    public uint dwMask;
    public Point ptMinSize;
    public Point ptMaxSize;
    public Point ptIntegral;
    public Point ptActual;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 255)]
    public String wszTitle;
    public uint dwModeFlags;
    public Int32 crBkgnd; 
}
```

The deskband API [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762067.aspx) clearly states that it is a deprecated API. It says:

> **Important**  You should use thumbnail toolbars in new development in place of desk bands, which are not supported as of Windows 7.

In other words, you should almost certainly not be solving your problem with the deskband API.

That said, if you want to learn how to use deskband API look for example code in C++. Don't restrict the search to C#. Expect to find good examples in C++ but not in C#.

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1 and on the Taskbar, Microsoft has implemented a DeskBand on the taskbar called Touch Keyboard - you click it and the touch keyboard opens. If it's deprecated, then I'm assuming they don't plan on getting rid of it anytime soon. Also, I dislike the Thumbnail toolbars, they are the exact opposite of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I'm only telling you what the official line is. Clearly you can do as you please. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @David, it's just a personal project that I've been trying to figure out for a long time. I just really need to finish it. Even if it may not work in the future :) All these errors are gone now! I am still unsure of which methods to call to actually get the DeskBand to appear on the taskbar and at which point to call these methods.

Comment: Look for example projects written in c++